# Idiomatic way of extracting known key-> val pairs from a string

Tags: scala

Example context:

An HTTP Response with a body as follows:

```
key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3.
```

The names of the keys are always known.

Currently the extraction is done with regex:

```
  val params = response split ("""&""") map { _.split("""=""") } map { el => { el(0) -> el(1) } } toMap;
```

Is there a simpler way of pattern matching the response for specific params?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think using `split` is probably going to be the fastest/simplest solution here. You're not doing any advanced parsing, so using parser combinators or regex capture groups seems a little overkill.

However, when you have complex expressions involving multiple calls to `map`, `filter`, etc., it's usually an indicator that you can clean things up with a for-comprehension:

```
val response = "key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3"
val params = (for { x <- response split ("&")
                    Array(k, v) = x split ("=") }
                yield k->v).toMap
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use parser combinators here for most flexibility and robustness (i.e., handle failed parsing):

```
object Parser extends RegexParsers with App {
  def lit: Parser[String] = "[^=&]+".r

  def pair: Parser[(String, String)] = lit ~ "=" ~ lit ^^ {
    case key ~ "=" ~ value => key -> value
  }

  def parse: Parser[Seq[(String, String)]] = repsep(pair, "&")

  val response = "key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3"
  val params = parse(new CharSequenceReader(response)).get.toMap
  println(params)
}
```

Comment: You could simplify your _pair_ parser quite a bit: `def pair: Parser[(String, String)] = lit ~ ("=" ~> lit) ^^ { x => (x._1, x._2) }`

Comment: With this formulation, the ^^ operator and subsequent function can be ommited, can't it? BTW, I did not write it like this as I find that parenthesis in parser combinations are not very natural.

Comment: If you omit the `^^` conversion part then the result type changes to `Parser[String~String]`, causing the `toMap` conversion to break. I agree that the extra parenthesis aren't ideal, but I still think getting rid of the literal parser in the result is worth it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regexp as a matcher like this:

```
val r = "([^=]+)=([^=]+)".r

 def toKv(s:String) = s match { 
    case r(k,v) => (k,v)
    case _ => throw InvalidFormatException
}
```

So, for your case it would look like:

```
response split ("&") map (toKv)
```

Comment: I'd note that in the cases of both patterns above, it's not necessary to use triple-quoted strings since you have no backslashes.

Comment: Fixed it, had just copied it from the OP's